# Choice of test in a pre-post scenario

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, manova

I would like to test whether there is a significant difference in outcome in a pre/post scenario.

**I have the following set-up:**

Measured level of concentration of A (`continuous`) in blood pre-death and measured concentration of A post-death for each individual (roughly 100 individuals in total).

**Working hypothesis:** After death, the concentration of A falls and hence should be on average lower then pre-death concentration.

So, my first impulse was to go for a `paired-t-test` given all assumptions are fulfilled.
However, my problem arises from the fact that the post-death concentration of A is not always measured at the same time after the death has occurred. So maybe 1h after death, sometimes 12h later and so on. I wonder if this causes any problems and whether I can somehow factor in the difference in post-death time-to-test.
(There are also other parameters which change on an individual basis: age, concentration, time, sex, cause of death; they are all categorical)

Is there any alternative approach to this or is the "significant difference" approach, given so many loose ends, just not reasonable at all? In the `paired t-test` I would just ignore all other parameters, though they might affect the concentration of A as well.

Another idea would be to use a `one-way MANOVA` with the dependent variables "pre-death_A" and "post-death_A" and the independent variables age, concentration, time, sex, cause of death.

I have never done this before so I am a bit hesitant. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze the data a bit more before forming the hypothesis; run a correlation and a multiple logistic regression on time after death of sample vs. concentration (including age, etc.). If time after death matters little, make your hypothesis simple: pre vs. post. If time after death does matter, then you'll want to form your hypothesis differently. You may need to set aside a training set & re-validate using the other set to avoid "torturing the data until it confesses" so to speak.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's really a good idea to first figure out whether time is a relevant factor or can be dropped. I'll definitely look into it...